# Difference between gravity and standing on a platform accelerating upwards at 9.81 m/s^2

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, free-fall

So, according to Einstein's theory of general relativity, gravity is not a force instead it is a consequence of objects with mass deforming spacetime, right? And so, according to him, there is no difference between standing on a platform accelerating upwards at 9.81 m/s^2 and standing on Earth, right? But, there is a difference. At least, I think it's a valid difference. If you drop two apples from a high altitude on Earth, not only will they accelerate downwards at 9.81m/s^2 but they will also slightly move towards each other because the Earth is a sphere and gravity acts radially inwards pulling the two apples closer to each other. But if you drop the apples from the same height above the accelerating platform, the apples will only appear to accelerate downwards at 9.81 m/s^2 but will not move towards each other like they would on Earth. Why is this true? Is this even a valid difference? If it isn't, why isn't it?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, the equivalence is only to first order. There would be no tidal forces in an elevator, but there are in the gravity of a (near) spherical body, which is inhomogeneous.

Comment: @CuriousOne What do you mean by "the equivalence is only to first order"?

Comment: The word you are looking for is "local".

Comment: It is only exact for homogeneous fields, which do not exist in nature, but the fields that do exist are "smooth", i.e. you can always find a small enough volume in which the field is homogeneous enough, so that the equivalence holds with sufficient precision.

Comment: @CuriousOne So, does the equivalence not work for orbits around planets happen because of the same reason?

Comment: The equivalence works perfectly fine for what it is supped to do, which, as @AccidentalFourierTransform has said, is only "local". In technical terms it is exact in the tangential spaces, but I will let the more theoretically inclined folks explain that.

Comment: " they accelerate downwards at 9.81m/s^2 but they will also slightly move towards each other" I think those two statements are incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalence principle applies only for a very small size lab, where it is not possible to make the parallel vs radial distinction you mentioned. Small size indicates, it is local.

More over, there are other ways to distinguish between the two, if the size of the lab is big enough. One example - gravity changes with height and the acceleration inside an accelerating lab would not. And that would enable the lab to use time dilation for the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

If the gravity is caused by an infinite plane of mass, then yes: the equivalence is exact. In this case, Einstein original viewed gravity as a consequence of gravitational time dilation. Enter Earth: now the apples' paths cross--much like 2 nearby people walking on great circles around Earth. Thus, he realized the metric of space-time is curved.